# Gazebo 1.4: model.config vs manifest.xml

Tags: gazebo-1.4, gazebo-model, gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the tutorial [Make a Mobile Robot](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/build_robot/mobile_base) for version 1.4 instead of creating `manifest.xml` for a model it is suggested to make `model.config`. However Gazebo 1.4.0 (built from source) does not see the model in this case. Everything works fine when I use `manifest.xml`.

Do I have an odd build or there is a mistake in tutorial?

Thanks,

Boris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1266/gazebo-1.4:-model.config-vs-manifest.xml/) by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo 1.4 will first attempt to find a `model.config` file. If a `model.config` doesn't exist, then Gazebo will attempt to find and use `manifest.xml`.

This is the behavior in the released version of Gazebo 1.4.

`manifest.xml` is being deprecated because it can be confounded with `manifest.xml` from ROS.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1